# Why elseif condition doesn't work?

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $datetime=date("d-m-y");
    $date1=date("d")+1;             
    $datetime1=date("$date1-m-y ");
    $date1=$date1+1;
    $datetime2=date("$date1-m-y ");
    $date1=$date1+1;
    $datetime3=date("$date1-m-y ");

    echo $_POST['date1'];
    echo $datetime1;


    if($_POST['date1']==$datetime1)
    {
        header("location:bus2.php");
    }

?>
```

here if condition doesn't work  even though `echo $_POST['date1'];` and `echo $datetime1;` shows the same result.

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to call `exit;` after `header("Location: $url");` if it is not the last line

Answer (score 7):

The values are **NOT** the same:

```
$datetime1=date("$date1-m-y ");
                           ^--this space makes all the difference:


$_POST['date1'] = '14-02-2014';
$datetime1      = '14-02-2014 ';
                             ^--- spot the difference
```